# How does the binomial expansion of $(1+(1/n))^n$ equal to the partial sum sequence of $(1/n!)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm kind of confused, because I'm not sure how this expression
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!n^k}
$$
simplifies to $$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}
$$

Could anybody help me out?

Comment: What you've written doesn't make much sense as the "simplified expression" has $n$ as the index so it goes to $\infty$.

Comment: It does not. Moreover (though it is not the crucial fact), the second sum is $+\infty$, because $k$ does not depend on $n$.

Comment: "k" is the index in both expressions, my bad. Just edited it.

Comment: In the first expression the sum goes up to $n$. In the limit $n\to\infty$ it converges to the second expression. Also each term ${n \choose k} \frac{1}{n^k}$ converges to $\frac{1}{k!}$.

Comment: @sometempname Hold on, how is the limit of the first expression 1/k! ?

Comment: In the second expression the sum goes to $\infty$. For each fixed $k$ you have ${n \choose k} \frac{1}{n^k} \to \frac{1}{k!}$ as $n\to\infty$, and the finite sum also converges to the infinite sum. There is no identity\simplification for any finite $n$ (except $k=0,1$).

Comment: These expressions are not equal. Even with $n=2$, we get $\frac94$ and $\frac52$.

Comment: @sometempname This is at best a heuristic argument, though. When $n\to\infty$, you change both the summands *and* the number of terms of the first sum, while the number of terms of the second one changes as well -- this is a good intuition, maybe, but barely more.

Comment: Ah, true. I had written down that they were equal in class, but surely then I must've forgotten to add that their limit was the same. 

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: I didn't give any argument, just stated the facts.

Comment: @sometempname "In the limit  $n\to\infty$  it converges to the second expression." No, it doesn't, since the second expression also has a $n$ in it.

Comment: Like I wrote above, the second sum should go to $\infty$ (the original post was different from the current one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As Clement C. already noted, the two expressions are not equivalent.  Here, we show that, in fact, $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$ for all $n\ge 1$.  Moreover, we show that as $n\to \infty$, both terms of interest approach the same value.  To that end, we proceed.

First, note that using the binomial theorem, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)}{n^k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac nn\right)\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)\cdots \left(\frac{n-k+1}{n}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Second, since all of the parenthetical terms in $(1)$ are less than $1$, we arrive at the first coveted relationship

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n \le \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}} \tag 2$$

for all $n\ge 1$.

Next, note that since all of the terms in the binomial expansion are positive, we have for any integer $0\le p<n$

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n \ge \sum_{k=0}^p \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k} \tag 3$$

Putting $(2)$ and $(3)$ together yields

$$\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k} \le \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n \le \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!} \tag 4$$

Since $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is monotonically increasing ([SEE THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263)) and bounded above by the convergent series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$, its limit exists.  Similarly, the sum on the left-hand side of $(4)$ is monotonically increasing in $n$ and bounded above.  Therefore, we may take the limit of $(4)$.  Proceeding, we find

$$\sum_{k=0}^p \frac{1}{k!} \le \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!} \tag 5$$

for all $p$.  Since the inequality on the left-hand side of $(5)$ is true fo all $p$, we can let $p\to \infty$ to reveal the coveted result

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}}$$

Comment: Wow, thank you too for your reply! It's quite informative, this is definitely going to help me out a lot.

Comment: Nice answer. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you!  Very much appreciative.  -Mark

Comment: @Matt24 You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

***tl;dr:*** the two are not equal, but have the same limit when $n$ goes to $\infty$.

---

**First:** You cannot "simplify the first to get the second." The two expressions are **not** equal.

Compute the first few terms to check that. I am lazy, so asked a software program to do it for me. The ratio of their first 10 terms (obtained with Mathematica):

```
 N[Table[(Sum[1/(k!), {k, 0, n}]/Sum[n!/(k! (n - k)! n^k), {k, 0, n}]), {n, 1, 10}] ]
```

> {1., 1.11111, 1.125, 1.10933, 1.09177, 1.0779, 1.06745, 1.05943,
>   1.05312, 1.04802}

*A plot (ditto)*

```
DiscretePlot[{Sum[1/(k!), {k, 0, n}], Sum[n!/(k! (n - k)! n^k), {k, 0, n}]}, {n, 1, 100}]
```

[image]

**However,** the two expressions *do* have the same limit when $n\to\infty$, namely $e$.

For the first, it is trivial based on [the series definition of $e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Representations):
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} = e
$$

For the second, observe that by the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \frac{1}{n^k}
= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}
= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e
$$
where the last step is a standard limit *(or, for some, this is the definition of $e$)*.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! I should've realized they weren't equal, what my professor must've said was that their limits were the same (and I didn't keep track of that).

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Nicely written.  +1